# Codeignitor Error Number: 1066 "Not unique table/alias"

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

What I am trying to do

```
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', $this->lang->line('signup_username'), 'required|callback__usernameRegex|min_length[5]|max_length[15]|is_unique[users.username]',
            array(
                'required'      => $this->lang->line('signup_username_missing'),
                'is_unique'     => $this->lang->line('signup_username_exists')
            )
        );
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', $this->lang->line('signup_email'), 'required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]',
            array(
                'required'      => $this->lang->line('signup_email_missing'),
                'is_unique'     => $this->lang->line('signup_email_exists')
            )
        );
```

username and email should be unique as expected so I'm using `is_unique[users.username]` and `is_unique[users.email]` to check for it, but as soon as I run

```
$this->form_validation->run()
```

I am getting error 1066

> Not unique table/alias: 'sdy_users'

and query it returns is

> SELECT * FROM `sdy_users`, `sdy_users` WHERE `username` = 'testu' AND `email` = 'test@sd.net' LIMIT 1

it is somehow adding the table name twice! Earlier it was working but I am failing to understand what is wrong!

Comment: could you show the code of your model where the query is generated?

Comment: there is no model really for this query, it's simple form validation library stuff, somehow it's related to 2 is_unique statements for username, email. It was working yesterday but can't seem to figure out what triggered this! Still looking!

Comment: the query must be generated somewhere, right?

Comment: you are right `$this->form_validation->run()` is creating the query, it still is working flawlessly on my dev server but started giving me wrong query on my localhost and I am failing to figure where I have messed up!

Comment: actually it does if you are using `is_unique`, here is the code `public function is_unique($str, $field) { sscanf($field, '%[^.].%[^.]', $table, $field); return isset($this->CI->db) ? ($this->CI->db->limit(1)->get_where($table, array($field => $str))->num_rows() === 0) : FALSE; }` and that is where it is adding the table name twice!

Comment: in my case reset_validation() won't work!

Comment: sorry, my bad, you are right

Comment: All I have to do is add one more line to the core lib `$this->CI->db->flush_cache();` and it works but I don't want to change a system lib and looking for a proper solution rather then a patchwork!!!

Comment: please update your question with your comments, to make it more clear/focused

Comment: why not extend the lib?

Comment: yes for sure, but I can't understand why this cache thing is happening in my localhost and not the host server!

Comment: you are right, better extend it!

Answer (score -1):

there is a problem in your query please correct it

```
SELECT * FROM sdy_users, sdy_users WHERE username = 'testu' AND email = 'test@sd.net' LIMIT 1
```

why are you using this twice ?? sdy_users, sdy_users ??
because of this system showing this error Not unique table/alias: 'sdy_users'

Comment: please read the question correctly, I'm using form_validation library, I'm not creating the query, the query is being created by the lib itself when I run `$this->form_validation->run()` and because I'm using `is_unique` directive twice for username, email it is adding the table name twice and I'm trying to figure out why! I know about it and looking for a solution!